Vitali convergence theorem applied to convergence of Schwartz functions
Let $\{ f_n\}$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions on the real line converging to a Schwartz function $f$. That is, derivatives of $\{ f_n\}$ of any order converge uniformly to those of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ faster than any polynomial.
In that case, I wonder how to prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f_n - f \rvert \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
I don't think the dominated convergence theorem works here, because the underlying measure space is not finite one.
So, the only route I can find is the Vitali Convergence Theorem, where I have to prove uniform integrability of $\{ f_n \}$ and another technical condition needed for infinite measures.
However, I do not see how to use Schwartz convergence to prove these conditions. I guess rate of convergence must somehow be used. Could anyone help me?
Add) Let me be more precise about convergence. For any $N,M \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, define $\lVert f \rVert_{N,M}:= \sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R} } \lvert (1+\lvert x \rvert)^N f^{(M)}(x) \rvert$. Then, $f_n \to f$ in the Schwartz space means that $\lVert f_n -f \rVert_{N,M} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $N,M$.

Well...I was dumb...
For any $N \geq 2$, let us compute
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f_n - f \rvert=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f_n(x)- f(x) \rvert \frac{(1+\lvert x \rvert)^N}{(1+\lvert x \rvert)^N}dx \leq \lVert f_n -f \rVert_{N,0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+\lvert x \rvert)^N} \to 0
\end{equation}
as $n \to \infty$.
We don't need those fancy convergence theorems...
If anyone finds any error, please let me know.
